# Deriving instances for higher-kinded data

Tags: haskell, type-families, higher-kinded-types

This question is based on the higher-kinded-data pattern, described in [this Reasonably Polymorphic blog post](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com//blog/higher-kinded-data).

In the following block of code, I define a type family `HKD` and a data type `Person`, where the fields may be either `Maybe` or `Identity`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies  #-}

import           Data.Aeson

-- "Higher Kinded Data" (http://reasonablypolymorphic.com//blog/higher-kinded-data)
type family HKD f a where
    HKD Identity a = a
    HKD Maybe a = Maybe a

data Person f = Person
  { pName :: HKD f String
  , pAge  :: HKD f Int
  } deriving (Generic)
```

I then attempt to derive a `ToJSON` instance for this type.

```
-- Already provided in imports:
-- instance ToJSON String
-- instance ToJSON Int
-- instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Maybe a)

instance ToJSON (Person f) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> No instance for `(ToJSON (HKD f Int))` arising from a use of `genericToJSON`.

Given that I already have `ToJSON Int` and `ToJSON (Maybe Int)`, shouldn't GHC be able to derive an instance `ToJSON (HKD f Int)`? My understanding is that type families act like type aliases with respect to instances. If that's the case, then I cannot define my own instances for it, but it should receive instances from its definions, in this case `Int` and `Maybe Int`. Unfortunately the error seems to contradict that.

How can I define a `ToJSON` instance for my type?

Comment: `instance (ToJSON (HKD f Int), ToJSON (HKD f String)) => ToJSON (Person f)`, no? (Requires `-XUndecidableInstances` of course, but those aren't too bad.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout This should be an answer :)

Comment: `instance ToJSON (Person f)` would imply `ToJSON (Person [])` which would involve the type `HKD [] Int` which has no JSON serializer (arguably, this type should not exists -- but it does!). Hence, you can not define `instance ToJSON (Person f)` without any context.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for the idea! That does compile, but the solution doesn't scale when the data type in question contains a large number of fields.

Comment: @chi Note that `HKD` only supports `Identity` and `Maybe` as defined in this question. I do not believe that `HKD [] Int` is valid here (though it is in the original blog post).

Comment: @MatthewPiziak It's perfectly valid. It's just *stuck*. `HKD Identity a` is not stuck and will reduce to `a`. `HKD [] a` is stuck (but valid) and simply doesn't reduce. You can even compute with it if you try hard enough, I think. Same for `Person []`. [See also](https://gelisam.blogspot.com/2017/11/computing-with-impossible-types.html)

Answer (score 8):

The type family `HKD` needs to be applied to a known `Identity` or `Maybe` to reduce. Otherwise, `HKD f Int` with an unknown `f` is just stuck, and we cannot resolve `HKD f a` constraints for all field types `a`, except by listing them in the context, for example `(ToJSON (HKD f Int), ToJSON (HKD f String))`,  which is one possible solution but doesn't scale well to large numbers of fields.

## Solution 1: Derive the context

The main problem is the tediousness of writing and maintaining the list of field constraints, this is solved by noting that it is really a function of the record type, and that we can define it in Haskell using GHC Generics.

```
type GToJSONFields a = GFields' ToJSON (Rep a)

-- Every field satisfies constraint c
type family GFields' (c :: * -> Constraint) (f :: * -> *) :: Constraint
type instance GFields' c (M1 i d f) = GFields' c f
type instance GFields' c (f :+: g) = (GFields' c f, GFields' c g)
type instance GFields' c (f :*: g) = (GFields' c f, GFields' c g)
type instance GFields' c U1 = ()
type instance GFields' c (K1 i a) = c a

instance (GToJSONFields (Person f)) => ToJSON (Person f) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

However this instance is nonmodular and inefficient, because it still exposes the internal structure of the record (its field types), and constraints for every single field must be re-solved every time `ToJSON (Person f)` is used.

[Gist of solution 1](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/67f8eca8b21d3cdb873b08ded24fdbfe)

## Solution 2: Generalize the context

What we really want to write as an instance is this

```
instance (forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (HKD f a)) => ToJSON (Person f) where
  -- ...
```

which uses a quantified constraint, a new feature currently being implemented in GHC; hopefully the syntax is self-descriptive. But since it is not released yet, what can we do in the meantime?

A quantified constraint is currently encodable using a type class.

```
class ToJSON_HKD f where
  toJSON_HKD :: ToJSON a => f a -> Value  -- AllowAmbiguousTypes, or wrap this in a newtype (which we will define next anyway)

instance ToJSON_HKD Identity where
  toJSON_HKD = toJSON

instance ToJSON_HKD Maybe where
  toJSON_HKD = toJSON
```

But `genericToJSON` would use `ToJSON` on the fields, not `ToJSON_HKD`. We can will wrap the fields in a `newtype` that dispatches `ToJSON` constraints with a `ToJSON_HKD` constraint.

```
newtype Apply f a = Apply (HKD f a)

instance ToJSON_HKD f => ToJSON (Apply f a) where
  toJSON (Apply x) = toJSON_HKD @f @a x
```

The fields of `Person` can only be wrapped in `HKD Identity` or `HKD Maybe`. We should add one more case for `HKD`. In fact, let's make it open, and refactor the case for type constructors. We write `HKD (Tc Maybe) a` instead of `HKD Maybe a`; this is longer, but the `Tc` tag can be reused for any other type constructor, e.g., `HKD (Tc (Apply f)) a`.

```
-- Redefining HKD
type family HKD f a
type instance HKD Identity a = a
type instance HKD (Tc f) a = f a

data Tc (f :: * -> *)  -- Type-level tag for type constructors
```

*aeson* has a `ToJSON1` type class whose role is quite similar to `ToJSON_HKD`, as an encoding of `forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)`. Serendipitously, `Tc` is just the right type to connect those classes.

```
instance ToJSON1 f => ToJSON_HKD (Tc f) where
  toJSON1_HKD = toJSON1
```

The next step is the wrapper itself.

```
wrapApply :: Person f -> Person (Tc (Apply f))
wrapApply = gcoerce
```

All we are doing is wrapping the fields in a `newtype` (from `HKD f a` to `HKD (Tc (Apply f)) a`, which is equal to `Apply f a` and representationally equivalent to `HKD f a`). So this is really a coercion. Unfortunately, `coerce` will not typecheck here, as `Person f` has a nominal type parameter (because it uses `HKD`, which matches on the *name* `f` to reduce). However, `Person` is a `Generic` type, and the generic representations of the input and expected output of `wrapApply` are in fact coercible. This gives rise to the following "generic coercion", which makes `wrapApply` superfluous:

```
gcoerce :: forall a b
        .  (Generic a, Generic b, Coercible (Rep a ()) (Rep b ()))
        => a -> b
gcoerce = to . (coerce :: Rep a () -> Rep b ()) . from
```

We conclude: wrap the fields in `Apply`, and use `genericToJSON`.

```
instance ToJSON_HKD f => ToJSON (Person f) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions . gcoerce @_ @(Person (Tc (Apply f)))
```

[Gist of solution 2](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/791164a92b279222acc212f39f5e8d26).

Note about the gist: `HKD` got renamed to `(@@)`, a name borrowed from [*singletons*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.4.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:-64--64-), and `HKD Identity a` is rewritten as `HKD Id a`, making an explicit distinction between the type constructor `Identity`, and the defunctionalized symbol `Id` for the identity function. It looks neater to me.

## Solution 3: Without type families

The HKD blog post combines two ideas:

1. Parameterizing records over a type constructor `f` (also called ["functor functor pattern"](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2017-12-15-functor-functors.html));
2. Generalizing `f` to be a type function, which is possible, even though Haskell doesn't have first-class functions at the type-level, thanks to [the technique of *defunctionalization*](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/).

The main goal of the second idea is to be able to reuse the record `Person` with unwrapped fields. That seems like quite a cosmetic concern for the amount of complexity type families introduce.

Looking closer, it could be argued that there is really not that much extra complexity. Is it worth it in the end? I don't have a good answer yet.

Just for reference, here's the result of applying the techniques above to a simpler record without the `HKD` type family.

```
data Person f = Person
  { name :: f String
  , age :: f Int
  }
```

We can remove two definitions: `ToJSON_HKD` (`ToJSON1` suffices), and `gcoerce` (`coerce` suffices). We replace `Apply` with this other newtype connecting `ToJSON` and `ToJSON1`:

```
newtype Apply' f a = Apply' (f a)  -- no HKD

instance (ToJSON1 f, ToJSON a) => ToJSON (Apply' f a) where
  toJSON (Apply' x) = toJSON1 x
```

And we derive `ToJSON` as follows:

```
instance ToJSON1 f => ToJSON (Person f) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions . coerce @_ @(Person (Apply' f))
```

---

## Caveat: Special field types

*aeson* has an option to make `Maybe` fields optional, so they are allowed to be missing in the corresponding JSON object. Well, that option doesn't work with the methods described above. It only affects the fields are known to be `Maybe` in the definition of the instance, so that fails for solutions 2 and 3 because of the newtypes around all fields.

Furthermore, for solution 1, this

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} ToJSON (Person Maybe) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions{omitNothingFields=True}
```

would behave differently from specializing this other instance *after the fact* to `Person Maybe`:

```
instance ... => ToJSON (Person f) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions{omitNothingFields=True}
```

Comment: Oooh `QuantifiedConstraints` is being implemented, fun.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to refactor out `gcoerce @_ @(Person (Tc (Apply f)))` from the `ToJSON` instance to DRY up the code a bit? In other words, everything stays the same except `Person` so can it be replaced with some `t`?

Comment: We can write `wrap :: (...) => p f -> p (Tc (Apply f)) ; wrap = gcoerce` which should be sufficiently specialized to allow `toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions . wrap` without extra annotations.

Answer (score 3):

author of the blog post here. Probably the easiest solution here is to just monomorphize your `f` parameter:

```
instance ToJSON (Person Identity) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions

instance ToJSON (Person Maybe) where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

It's kind of ugly, but certainly shippable. I'm in the lab currently trying to figure out better general solutions to this problem, and will let you know if I come up with anything.